# ExecutorService, Future, Threads appears Actives when all Runnables must be finished

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, runnable

I have a complex program, using Runnable, ExecutorService and Future.

I want to know why the Runnable/Threads appears running, and my application still running, when I hope all they must be finished.

The Complete Code **You can Copy & Paste, and Run, all you need is here.**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class TestFutureExecutorService {

  public static void main(String... args) {

    List<Future<?>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    RunnableTest rt = new RunnableTest("rt", futureList, executorService);

    new Timer(false).schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        rt.stop();
      }
    }, ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(100L, 500L));

    System.out.println("Let's go to check the threads status.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < futureList.size(); i++) {//Working!
      try {
        if (futureList.get(i) != null) {
          futureList.get(i).get();
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Apparently everything is finished.\n");

    boolean allDone = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < futureList.size(); i++) {
      if (futureList.get(i) != null) {
        allDone &= futureList.get(i).isDone(); // check if future is done
      }

    }
    System.out.println("Is everything really finished?:" + allDone + ".\n");
    //executorService.shutdown();

    Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
    thisThread.setName("Admin Thread");
    thisThread.setPriority(1);
    System.out.println("Thread = " + thisThread);

    int count = Thread.activeCount();
    System.out.println("currently active threads = " + count);

    Thread activeThreadsArray[] = new Thread[count];
    Thread.enumerate(activeThreadsArray);
    // prints active threads
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      System.out.println(i + ": " + activeThreadsArray[i]);
    }

  }

  public static class RunnableTest implements Runnable {
    private final String name;
    private final List<Future<?>> futureList;
    private final ExecutorService executorService;
    private volatile boolean isRunning = false;

    public RunnableTest(String name, List<Future<?>> futureList, ExecutorService executorService) {
      this.name = name;
      this.futureList = futureList;
      this.executorService = executorService;
      this.futureList.add(this.executorService.submit(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      Thread.currentThread().setName(Thread.currentThread().getName() + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ":" + name);
      isRunning = true;
      while (isRunning) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(50);
          new Processor(this.futureList, this.executorService);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
      }
        System.out.println("Finishing:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public void stop() {
      isRunning = false;
    }

  }

  public static class Processor implements Runnable {

    private final List<Future<?>> futureList;
    private final ExecutorService executorService;

    public Processor(List<Future<?>> futureList, ExecutorService executorService) {
      this.futureList = futureList;
      this.executorService = executorService;
      this.futureList.add(this.executorService.submit(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      String hour = new SimpleDateFormat("_yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSSS_").format(new Date());
      Thread.currentThread().setName(hour + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        try {
          int timeSleeping = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100, 300);
          Thread.sleep(timeSleeping);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("Finishing:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
  }

}
```

Now, the output....

```
Let's go to check the threads status.

Finishing:_20190923-203808.0435_Processor
Finishing:_20190923-203808.0437_Processor
Finishing:_20190923-203808.0489_Processor
Finishing:pool-1-thread-1->RunnableTest:rt
Finishing:_20190923-203808.0695_Processor
Finishing:_20190923-203808.0544_Processor
Finishing:_20190923-203808.0593_Processor
Finishing:_20190923-203808.0746_Processor
Finishing:_20190923-203808.0645_Processor
Apparently everything is finished.

Is everything really finished?:true.

Thread = Thread[Admin Thread,1,main]
currently active threads = 8
0: Thread[Admin Thread,1,main]
1: Thread[pool-1-thread-1->RunnableTest:rt,5,main]
2: Thread[Timer-0,5,main]
3: Thread[_20190923-203808.0593_Processor,5,main]
4: Thread[_20190923-203808.0695_Processor,5,main]
5: Thread[_20190923-203808.0746_Processor,5,main]
6: Thread[_20190923-203808.0544_Processor,5,main]
7: Thread[_20190923-203808.0645_Processor,5,main]
```

When I run the application, in my IDE, remain something "running", But all Runnable must be finished!

**Why Threads appears active?** **What means that?**

**How finishes all?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ExecutorService. ExecutorService keep the threads alive to be ready for the next tasks. You have to tell ExecutorService that you don't have anymore task and it can discards the threads.

You can do this by calling method

```
 `shutdown() or shutdownNow()`
```

So uncomment the line in your code after done check:

```
 System.out.println("Is everything really finished?:" + allDone + ".\n");
    //executorService.shutdown();
```

Your application will still not finish because you create the timer thread as non-deamon thread, that means JVM will not stop if running non-deamon thread exists in your application.

You can create the timer as deamon thread like this:

```
new Timer(true).schedule(new TimerTask() {
```

Comment: Later I post my question, I get the answer with the same result but Without Explanation. Thank to you I understand the reasons.